# Where online can I post my (free) rules and materials for games I've created?

Tags: online, game-development

I'm looking for websites that specialize in providing rules and digital resources for card/board games online. Recently I've been creating lots of simple games for my design classes and I would like to post my work online for others to play (or ignore if they so choose). To be clear I'm not looking for a place to sell games nor am I looking to create an online computer version of the game. I simply want to post the rules and materials online where someone who is interested in indie games can find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the first place that jumps to mind for me is boardgamegeek.com

This forum seems like an appropriate place to post your rules and materials:
http://boardgamegeek.com/forum/26/boardgamegeek/board-game-design

You might consider setting up a tumblr or some other website you control and link the materials and information in the forum.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give boardgamegeek a look and mark your answer as correct if it looks like an appropriate match. I've thought about using my own website or setting up a tumblr (as you suggested) but I feel that people would be less likely to stumble upon it unless I posted random spam links everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The [Card and Board Game Designers Guild (on Facebook)](https://www.facebook.com/groups/320445024722916/) is a great source of criticism and suggestions. I'm not sure how well the idea of "hosting finished files" works with the stated purpose of the Guild, but it's good to know about regardless!

If you end up going with a blog of some sorts, you might consider posting at [/r/tabletopgamedesign](http://www.reddit.com/r/tabletopgamedesign).

Answer (score 0):

At the [pagat.com Invented Card Games](http://www.pagat.com/invented/) page, John enables contributions. Some entries are whole web page descriptions of a game, while other entries are a link to a description elsewhere.